# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_GDTCCTConstructiOSClientInfo", referenced from:

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_GDTCCTConstructiOSClientInfo", referenced from:
_GDTCCTConstructClientInfo in libGoogleDataTransportCCTSupport.a(GDTCCTNanopbHelpers.o)
"_GDTCORNetworkMobileSubTypeMessage", referenced from:
_GDTCCTNetworkConnectionInfoNetworkMobileSubtype in libGoogleDataTransportCCTSupport.a(GDTCCTNanopbHelpers.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I run project in xcode 14.3 , Can I help you . [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chCrW.png)

Comment: #include <unistd.h>
#include <libkern/OSAtomic.h>
 i add 2 line above to file have issue

Answer (score 1):

this issue is related to Google Data transport library from pod , you can do fix in this way just go to your pods folder and delete Google data transport and then

> pod update GoogleDataTransport
> open your xcworkspace again and do once clean and rebuild your project.
> It must work now
> if issue still facing kindly connect with me

Comment: can i help you , i still issue

Comment: @DeveloperSoftware yes tell me if there any specific solution